# Simple node.js server for relaying GPS coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, swift

So I'm attempting to create an app that would be able to track the location of a ferry crossing a river. I'm not quite sure what form of GPS device I'll be putting on the ferry, however regardless of this I need this GPS to relay it's coordinates to a server. This server will then output the coordinates  to all iOS clients connected via the app, the app will then update the marker on Apple Maps to reflect the received coordinate.

I have the app all coded, however, what I need now is a server capable of achieving what I need. Which is to receive coordinates from GPS, and relay them to iOS devices connected. I'm not quite sure what language/technology would be involved in this, however after some googling I believe running a node.js server on heroku would give promising results.

Does anybody know how to code the kind of simple server I need? Or could you perhaps suggest an alternate method for getting my GPS coordinates to the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create this simple server I was after:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am now working through a problem with my Heroku server that says my server couldn't bind a port to $PORT and timed out, but this all works locally.

Comment: Try ``http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){`` on that line instead, like I showed you in my answer...

Comment: Also, node does not recommend that you use the ``http.Server`` object directly. You should be using ``var http = require('http').createServer(app);`` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you've formatted the data you intend to send to the server. Are they in POST requests? A websocket message? This is a very broad question, and involves a lot of explanation. You should probably elaborate a lot more on how your data is formatted and in what way you're sending it to the server. I can say that node.js is very versatile and provides a great environment for doing exactly what you want, how you want it if you're good with JavaScript, but it's difficult to say exactly what you need to do. I will give you some advice for getting started with node.js and heroku though.

Assuming you've already installed [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [git](http://git-scm.com/), made an account with [heroku](https://heroku.com/), and installed the [heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), and set up your account (`$ heroku login`) and [ssh keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys), the fastest way to get a basic server running with node.js on heroku is the following:

```
$ mkdir my-node-app
$ cd my-node-app
$ npm init
(follow the prompts)
```

Make a file named `Procfile` in the repository folder with the body

```
web: node app.js
```

Make a file named `app.js` in the repository folder with the body

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080); // for heroku
```

Then make a folder `static` in the repository folder, and in `static` make a file named `index.html` with the body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My node app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then run

```
$ npm install express --save
$ node app.js # this is optional, open localhost:8080 to test, control-C to kill
$ git init
$ heroku apps:create
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git push heroku master
```

Unless you give information on exactly how your data is formatted and transferred, this is the only way I know how to help you.